# Redux form and isomorphic-fetch always submits blank form to server

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, redux

I have a component and a container for an `add-user-form`. The following is the logic from my container.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import AddUserForm from '../components/AddUserForm';

export const fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'add-user-form',
  fields,
  onSubmit(doc) {
    return fetch('/api/v1/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(doc)
    });
  }
})(AddUserForm);
```

I did this [as per the docs recommendation](https://github.com/github/fetch#post-json). However, when this reaches my express server, it always logs a blank object, despite it being fully populated and correct in the client.

```
// mounted on `/api/v1/users`
routes.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // => {}
  // ...
})
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do you post json from redux form to a server with `isomorphic-fetch`?

Comment: Hi, @corvid! If you can add a working example using `jsbin` or similar, that would help us better understand the problem. Did you check whether `doc` contains your object as expected? Also, did you check on the Network tab that the request body is being sent?

Comment: Sure, I checked the network tab. I see that the request payload does in fact contain the correct request body. It has the request method of POST to the correct request URL and everything, it looks like everything checks out on the client

Comment: You do have body-parser and CORS set up on the server, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use express midleware body parser:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then try it:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you sir, I had `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed as well. Had     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) as well and couldn't access the body of the request until I changed it to app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

Thanks!